# How to convert YY format to YYYY format in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection called `members` and here is a sample data:

```
{
    "_id": 123,
    "name": "Jackie",
    "dob": "31/12/18"
}
```

Is it possible to convert the dd/mm/yy format to dd/mm/yyyy? As $dateFromString only accepts the latter.

(p.s. $toString/$toInt/$toDecimal is not supported as the MongoDB version is before version 4)

Comment: Have you tried changing the format inside `$dateToString`? Something like `{ $dateToString: { format: "%d-%m-%Y", date: "$dob" } }`

Comment: @zx01 do you mean specifying the format?

Comment: Ohh yess. My mistake should have been `$dateFromString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/ then https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/ to get the format you want.